# Getting PFUser's username (Parse.com)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get the username of a PFUser. The code below works without this line:`var username = nameId.username as String` but when it is added the collection view does not show any results.
Any ideas?

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Chat")
    //        query.whereKey("user", equalTo:currentUser)
    query.whereKey("rideId", equalTo:currentObjectId)
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            for object in objects {
                NSLog("%@", object.objectId)

                var testId = object.objectId

                println(testId)

                self.orderedIdArray.append(testId)

                var message = object.objectForKey("message") as String
                self.messageString = message
                self.messageArray.append(self.messageString)
                println(message)

                var nameId = object.objectForKey("user") as PFUser
                var username = nameId.username as String
                self.nameString = username
                self.namesArray.append(self.nameString)

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is now working with this line:

`query.includeKey("user")`

Comment: If this answers our question, please accept the answer so as to remove this question from the "Unanswered Questions" list.

Comment: Unfortunatly I am unable to do it at the moment. It is asking me to wait 23 Hours.